# PHP regarding lower and uppercase entries into MYSQL dbase

Tags: php, mysql, lowercase

I recently purchased a website with all contents, Whilst looking through the PHP scripts I noticed that all the MYSQL entries were all in Uppercase example below

```
$r=$db->Execute("SELECT USERNAME FROM PLAYER WHERE AUTHORIZED = 'Y' AND USERNAME LIKE ".$db->qstr("%".stripslashes($_GET["SEARCH"])."%")." ORDER BY USERNAME LIMIT ".(10*$page).",11");
```

Notice how its all Uppercase well there are 350+ files like this one and I want them all to become lowercase on the script and in PHPMYADMIN which at moment is displaying the table names as lowercase but all the fields are in Uppercase.

My question is, Is there a way to make all lowercase without going through every file and altering the statements, You're probably saying why don't you just leave it as uppercase, well the site in question allows me to sell work I've done but I don't want a whole script in uppercase as not many people would be happy with this method.

Comment: Uppercase is the defacto standard for the command structure in SQL, so to change that would be going against the generally accepted practice.

Comment: I just mainly want the table names in php and mysql to be lowercase  I understand words like SELECT, INSERT, FROM, AND, DELETE are the uppercase i just want the table names, rows fields to be lowercase. Hope that makes sense..

Comment: I'm just wondering if you ave actually tested your assumption that upper case would be unacceptable by asking potential customers? If not, you would be wasting effort to undertake this task at all ...